# Excel: When I use =A1 I want the cell to copy the cell as well as the font formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, fontconfig

I'm creating "Bingo" style cards in Excel for a maths lesson. On my master sheet I have x^2 (the 2 is superscript). When I use =A1 to duplicate the cell it doesn't copy the font formatting. In stead I get x2. Help!?!?!

Comment: Not sure if this is doable, but i might have a workaround for your x². There are special characters for the ² and ³. Alt+0178 and Alt+0179 will give you these and Excel will not mess them up. If of course you use a German keyboard you can just do AltGr+2/3.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. Using =A1, you only request what value is stored in that cell. Formatting cannot be copied using a formula. Formatting can be changed using conditional formatting though, but I bet you just need to preformat the cells.

Copy the content of A1, make a selection of all cells, right click and choose paste-special, and select formatting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but the idea is to create 32+ sets from one table. Since I want each worksheet to be unique, I'd have to spend a lot of time copy+pasting if I did it this way.

Comment: Yup. In other words, Excel is not the tool for the job you need. Have you considered Access?